# How to initialize Multiple paintComponents?

Tags: java

I'm new to java, and am required to make a game.

The problem I ran into and have tried to solve for the past two hour sis how to draw an image using Jpanel and paintComponent in two different classes. I can't seem to make it work.

Here's the code for my second class

```
public class Background extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public Background() {

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test_bg.png"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error loading background image");
        }
        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    }

}
```

This is pretty much the same thing as in my level class but this doesn't appear on the screen. For reasons not worth mentioning I need this to be a separate class.

Thanks.

Comment: If the image exists this code looks fine. The problem likely comes from somewhere else.

Comment: Make sure you are adding the Background to your JFrame, and that it is not under the other frames.

Comment: karl, how would I do that?

Comment: use a layout. frame.getContentPane().addComponent(mypanel, BorderLayout.WEST);     Then for the other panel add it with EAST.

Answer (score -1):

Your code here works, a black rectangle appears on the JPanel.

I suspect you are adding other JPanels on top of this one.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Background extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().add(new Background());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(800, 600);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private BufferedImage image;

    public Background() {

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test_bg.png"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error loading background image");
        }
        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    }

}
```

Comment: what are you saying?? "your solution works"?? is that an answer??

Comment: yes that's what I'm asking, how can I have two, I know it should work alone